# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') angular unit test

Tags: angular, ngrx, subscription

I am trying to update item, I wrote a function which gets the items from the store and update with new item based on user's selection with **this.name** and **this.price** but the same item.id that is intended for update.

```
   public updateItemData(){
    return this.store.select(itemSelector).subscribe(item => {
        this.updatedItem = {
            id: item.id,
            name: this.name,
            price: this.price
        }
    })
    }
```

This works perfectly without any issue but in a unit test.

```
it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

It marked green but with displayed error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

When I ran the project, I didn't get any error concerning the "undefined property" or whatever. I started writing the test

Please help to resolve this. I will appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Add a spyOn for the store service select. Either inside test or beforeEach

```
spyOn(store, 'select').and.returnValue(YOUR_VALUE);
```

make sure to declare store and asiign value inside `beforeEach`

```
let store: Store;
store = TestBed.inject(Store); // inside beforeEach
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did.

Comment: Return observable 
  `select').and.returnValue(of(YOUR_VALUE))`

Comment: Yes, I did but I think I didn't check if there is this.item === undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `provideMockStore` provided from `ngrx` like this:

**yourcomponent.component.spec.ts**

```js
import { provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';

describe('...', () => {
 ...  
 ...
 const myMockItemSelectorValue = {...};

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [...],
      imports: [...],
      providers: [
       { 
         initialState: { items: {...}, users: {...} }, // an initial mock Store
         selectors: [{ selector: itemSelector, value: myMockItemSelectorValue }]
       }
      ]
    })
  })
});
```

Or create a mock of the store using `jasmine` like the following:

```js
const mockStore = jasmine.createSpyObj<Store>('Store', ['select']);


beforeEach(() => mockStore.select.and.retunValue(of(TheDesiredMockValue))

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     providers: [{ provide: Store, useValue: mockStore }]
  })
})
```

Personally, I prefer the first option since I can specify multiple `selectors` with the respective mock values with an initial mock state.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is to

```
  if(this.item === undefined) 
        {
            return
        }
```

So in my component.ts

```
  public updateItemData(){
    return this.store.select(itemSelector).subscribe(item => {
     if(this.item === undefined) 
        {
            return
        }
        this.updatedItem = {
            id: item.id,
            name: this.name,
            price: this.price
        }
    })
    }
```

All error disappeared and mocking using *overrideSelector* was successful.

Comment: What is "this.item"? Looks like you're mixing class members and locale variables here. 

And beyond that, an emty return is pretty bad style. Make the condition `if (item !== undefined)` instead, then you can save yourself this pointless return.

Check your test, if it really tests something.

Comment: Thanks... i have adjusted it.